# How to get the price of eth (in INR) in a smart contract?

Tags: solidity, oracles, chainlink

I want to create a stablecoin like DAI, but instead of pegging to usd, I want to peg it to INR. The problem is I'm not able to find a chainlink pricefeed for ETH to INR.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is `INR/USD` data feed which will allow us to calculate the `ETH/INR`, using `ETH/USD`. You can follow [this example](https://docs.chain.link/docs/data-feeds/price-feeds/#getting-a-different-price-denomination) from the official docs.

The denomination formula would look like this:

[image: formula]

Here is the example code which you can use as your starting point:

```js
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol";

/**
 * Network: Mainnet
 * Base: ETH/USD
 * Base Address: 0x5f4eC3Df9cbd43714FE2740f5E3616155c5b8419
 * Quote: INR/USD
 * Quote Address: 0x605D5c2fBCeDb217D7987FC0951B5753069bC360
 * Decimals: 8
 */

/**
 * THIS IS AN EXAMPLE CONTRACT THAT USES HARDCODED VALUES FOR CLARITY.
 * THIS IS AN EXAMPLE CONTRACT THAT USES UN-AUDITED CODE.
 * DO NOT USE THIS CODE IN PRODUCTION.
 */

contract PriceConverter {
    function getDerivedPrice(address _base, address _quote, uint8 _decimals)
        public
        view
        returns (int256)
    {
        require(_decimals > uint8(0) && _decimals <= uint8(18), "Invalid _decimals");
        int256 decimals = int256(10 ** uint256(_decimals));
        ( , int256 basePrice, , , ) = AggregatorV3Interface(_base).latestRoundData();
        uint8 baseDecimals = AggregatorV3Interface(_base).decimals();
        basePrice = scalePrice(basePrice, baseDecimals, _decimals);

        ( , int256 quotePrice, , , ) = AggregatorV3Interface(_quote).latestRoundData();
        uint8 quoteDecimals = AggregatorV3Interface(_quote).decimals();
        quotePrice = scalePrice(quotePrice, quoteDecimals, _decimals);

        return basePrice * decimals / quotePrice;
    }

    function scalePrice(int256 _price, uint8 _priceDecimals, uint8 _decimals)
        internal
        pure
        returns (int256)
    {
        if (_priceDecimals < _decimals) {
            return _price * int256(10 ** uint256(_decimals - _priceDecimals));
        } else if (_priceDecimals > _decimals) {
            return _price / int256(10 ** uint256(_priceDecimals - _decimals));
        }
        return _price;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can deploy a contract with a variable of the conversion rate.

Than create a function that sets the conversion rate and make it controlled by wallets you trust.

There is an example like this: https://fiatcontract.com/#implement